# What term describes the classification of "non-fiction/fiction"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose there is a form like this, describing a book:

```
Title: Farming in the Alps
Author: C. Chaplin
Year: 1995
_______: non-fiction
```

Which term belongs in the blank?

Comment: _Genre_, _genre category_, _division_, _super-genre_

Comment: Or you could also use *Classification* or *Class.* The [Dewey Decimal System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dewey_Decimal_classes#Class_800_.E2.80.93_Literature) used by libraries is made up of Classes, Divisions, and Sections.

Answer (score 4):

Type. Anything more specific is too specific. Eight of the ten *classes* of the Dewey Decimal System are categories of non-fiction, doing away with *division* as well. (A ninth, Literature, is mainly fictional. The tenth, Philosophy, isn't truly either one.) *Genre* is usually a smaller grouping, whether fictional (e.g., murder mysteries) or non-fictional (e.g., military history). *Classification* suggests a taxonomic system of some kind, and that's not the case here. The distinction is binomial: between fiction and non-fiction, variously understood as narrative and expository work, literary and informational, invented and discovered, fanciful (or, harshly, false) and true, imaginative and prosaic. Except in U.S. elementary and secondary public education, where "non-fiction" is to represent 50% or more of the assigned reading from now on in most states, it's hard to imagine a situation when one would want or need to identify a work as non-fiction rather than history, science, anthropology, business, or some similar category.

Comment: I would have used "type", but in my personal catalogue of media I share a table for different media types like books, manga, movies, series, albums and games. So the field name "type" is already taken to denote the type of media. Thinking to go with "category" in that case as it sounds most natural.